# Proof that subspace of $L^2\{\mathbb{R}\}$ is Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, cauchy-sequences

I would like to understand whether or not the following subspace of $L^2{[0,\infty)}$ is also a Hilbert space.

Let $H[0,\infty]$ be a subspace of $L^2{[0,\infty)}$, with inner product $\langle f, g\rangle=\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)g(x)dx$,  with the added conditions:

1. for every $f\in H, f(x)=f(1/x)$
2. $f(0)=0$. I am not sure if this condition is strictly needed as condition 1 combined with the fact that this is a subspace of $L^2$ should ensure that $f(0)=0$.

I am unsure how to proceed with the proof.

My initial instinct is to try to show that $H$ is a complete subspace of $L^2{[0,\infty)}$ and hence a Hilbert space but don't know how to properly deal with Cauchey Sequences. Is this the correct approach here?

Comment: Do you mean $L^2[0,\infty)$?

Comment: You can simply show that it is a closed subspace. This is equivalent with completeness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your space $H$ is closed and thus complete, since $L^2$ is itself complete, i.e. conditions 1 and 2 pass to limits.

The trick here is the following measure-theoretic lemma: if $(f_n)\subset L^p$ is a sequence of functions s.t. $\|f_n-f\|_{L^p}\to0$, then there exists a subsequence $(f_{n_k})$ of $(f_n)$ that converges to $f$ almost everywhere.

Thus if $(f_n)\subset H$ and $f_n\to f\in L^2$ for some $f\in L^2$, then pass to a subsequence $f_{n_k}$ that converges a.e. to $f$ and thus
$$f(x)=\lim_kf_{n_k}(x)=\lim_kf_{n_k}(\frac{1}{x})=f(\frac{1}{x}) $$
almost everywhere.

Condition 2 in general doesn't make any sense since elements of $L^2$ are formally not functions but equivalence classes of a.e. equal functions, but if you were working say with $C_0(\mathbb{R})\cap L^2(\mathbb{R})$ then the same lemma would work to prove condition 2.

You can find a proof of this lemma in Folland's book for example.

Comment: thank you for the answer. is condition 2 even necessary then? i understand elements of $L^2$ are equivalence classes of functions, but doesn't the symmetry condition 1 guarantee that $f(0)=0$?

Comment: @MaxJames As I said, saying "let $f\in L^p$ and $x_0$ be a point. What is the value $f(x_0)$?" does not make any sense. Just consider $g(x)=f(x)$ for all $x\neq x_0$ and $g(x_0)=f(x_0)+1$. These are a.e. equal, so they are the same function in $L^p$, but have different values at $x_0$.

Comment: I may as as a different question, but $C_0(\mathbb{R})$ is the space of continuous functions that vanish at $\infty$ and $C_0(\mathbb{R})\cap L^2(\mathbb{R})$ is space of square integrable functions that are also in $C_0(\mathbb{R})$ and a Hilbert Space with ip $\langle f, g\rangle=\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)g(x)dx$?

Comment: @MaxJames that;s right :)

Comment: thanks again!!!